# How to setup Network map server in Corda?

Tags: corda

Can someone help me with the Steps or Instructions to create a Network Map Server in Corda ?

In the [Network Map](https://docs.corda.net/network-map.html#http-network-map-protocol) in Corda docs, I see this can be done in two ways. One with the additional-node-info's which we use the help of [Network Bootstrapper](https://docs.corda.net/network-bootstrapper.html), which is clear. And the other [HTTP network map protocol](https://docs.corda.net/network-map.html#http-network-map-protocol) is not clear. It would be great if someone shares the steps in detail to create network map server that distributes information across the nodes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The Cordite Foundation has released an open-source network map implementation: https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service. You can use this as a reference to see how a network map can be implemented.

Comment: Not sure if it's particular to this implementation, but executing "--initial-registration" on the Notary node registers it as a normal Node, not as a Notary.

Comment: To denote a node as being a notary node, it requires a priviledged operation on the NMS. To do this you need to call the REST api to upload the notary's nodeInfo. See https://network-map-test.cordite.foundation/swagger/#/admin/post_admin_api_notaries_validating

Comment: using curl `curl -X POST -H “Authorization: Bearer <token>” -H “accept: text/plain” -H “Content-Type: application/octet-stream” --data-binary @nodeInfo-007A0CAE8EECC5C9BE40337C8303F39D34592AA481F3153B0E16524BAD467533 http://localhost:8080//admin/api/notaries/validating`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because I am not skilled in Kotlin, I use Java to build a simple Corda [Doorman](https://github.com/PatrickPan2012/corda/tree/corda-release-V3/corda-doorman) and [Network Map](https://github.com/PatrickPan2012/corda/tree/corda-release-V3/corda-networkmap) Service after reading the source codes of Corda and [Cordite](https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service). You can check them out from Github. Thanks.